# Width & height of a WatchViewStub

Tags: android, wear-os

I am using a [`WatchViewStub`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WatchViewStub.html) on a watch activity with android wear (API 23).

I am trying to get its width and height of my activity's view as I want to do some calculation from the touch events relative to the center of the view.

Unfortunately, both my stub view's `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` always return `0`, even if I wait for the layout to be inflated by setting a listener with [`setOnLayoutInflatedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener.html).

How can I fetch the actual size of the a `WatchViewStub` ?

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
 Log.d(TAG, stub.getWidth()); // -> 0
 Log.d(TAG, stub.getHeight()); // -> 0

 stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
       Log.d(TAG, stub.getWidth()); // -> 0
       Log.d(TAG, stub.getHeight()); // -> 0
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You may be calling functions too early. Try overriding `onMeasure`

Comment: @jitinsharma Thanks. However I prefer a solution where I do not have to override the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
stub.getViewTreeObserver()
        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                stub.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                Log.d(TAG, "dimens = " + stub.getWidth() + " x " + stub.getHeight());
            }
        });
```